# NCurses: Insert panel in the middle of stacking order

Tags: c++, panel, ncurses, tui

I've read the following at [ 1 ] and I'm sorry if this has an obvious answer, but how do you insert a panel into the middle of a stacking order with regard to NCurses? Do you delete them all using `del_panel()` and re-add them with `new_panel()`, before doing a `update_panels()` and `doupdate()`? Any solutions to this will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

[ 1 ] - http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/panels.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) is a good first step:

- you can use `hide_panel` to remove a panel from the panel-stack without deleting (and re-creating it),
- you can use `show_panel` to add a panel back — on top of the stack,
- so removing all of the panels and re-adding them in the order that you want to display them will let you "insert" a new panel in the middle.

The `del_panel` function would not only hide the panel, but deallocate it, so you would have to create a new panel (with whatever contents) to get one that looked like the original.

Comment: Oh wow, Thomas! I'm a /huge/ fan of your software development work and never expected a personal reply from you :) But I do keep forgetting the value of manual pages, yes, as one of my friends often points out. Thank you though, this will work wonderfully.